# Python: Comparing columns in very large CSV efficiently

Tags: python, loops, csv

I have two `csv` files (that are actually tab delimited)

File 1 has 650,214 rows. It is is formatted with ID numbering going down the first column (not sequential).

File 2 has 7,901,252 rows. It is formatted like this:

`[ ID number | lang | other data]`. For example: `[64 | deu | Guten Tag]`

If the ID number in File 2 appears in the column with the ID number in File 1, and it has the `lang` I am interested in, I want to copy that row in File 2 to a dictionary.

First, I put all the ID numbers from File 1 in a list:

```
savedIDs = []
targetLang = 'deu'
phrases = {}

with open('File1.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file1:
    reader = csv.reader(file1, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        savedIDs.append(row[0])
```

That happens fairly quickly. Then I iterate through File2, checking against the list and saving into a dictionary:

```
with open('File2.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file2:
    reader = csv.reader(file2, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        if row[1] == targetLang and row[0] in savedIDs:
            phrases[row[0]] = (row[2], []) # second value gets filled in later with translation
```

This second part takes unacceptably long, maybe 3 rows a second.

Is there a way this can be done a lot quicker? Should I use PANDAS or another module to process the `csv`s?

Comment: One easy optimization is to make `savedIDs` a `set`.  That will make the `row[0] in savedIDs` operation O(1) instead of O(N).

Comment: Yes..with pandas is more easy and efficient..

Comment: `Pandas` if you can fit all of file 2 in memory, if not then `dask` may be a better option.

Comment: @0x5453 This worked very nicely. Thanks a lot.